# How to make this code validate before going to the next page?

Tags: jquery, html

The problem with this html fieldset form code is that when I click the submit button it does go to the next page but If I remove "next" from the button class it validates but it does not go to the next page.Fix it for me please.

The problem with this html fieldset form code is that when I click the submit button it does go to the next page but If I remove "next" from the button class it validates but it does not go to the next page.Fix it for me please.

The problem with this html fieldset form code is that when I click the submit button it does go to the next page but If I remove "next" from the button class it validates but it does not go to the next page.Fix it for me please.

I have repeated the above details because for some reason I could not post my code,sorry for that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "[http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd)">
<html xmlns="[http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml)">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">
fieldset {
border: 0;
}

</style>
</head>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url("ok.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* comment */


button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

}


</style>


<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <fieldset>
  <br><br><br><br>
    <label>Q1</label>

    <form id="myForm1">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Book" value="" required><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Second Book" value="" required ><br>

    </div>
</form>
  <button class="next btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="ShowText1();"  >Submit form</button>


<script>
    function ShowText1(){
    // find each input field inside the 'myForm' form:
    var inputs = myForm1.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // declare 'box' variable (textarea element):
    var box = document.getElementById('show');
    // clear the 'box':
    box.value = '';
    // loop through the input elements:
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        // append 'name' and 'value' to the 'box':
        box.value +=inputs[i].value+'\n';
    }
}
</script>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>

    <label>Q2</label>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input id="show" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Books"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="age"  placeholder="Age"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Status"/><br/>

</form>
    <button ID="idsend" type="submit"  >Submit</button>

</fieldset>


</section>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var len=$("section:first").children().length;
var i=0;
var s=0;
$(".next").click(function(){
i++;
if(len==i){
var p=$(this).parent().parent('section').next();
p.show();
p.children().first().show();
len=0;
i=0;
len=p.children().length;

$(this).parent().parent().hide();

}
else{
$(this).parent().next().show();
$(this).parent().hide();
}
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("section").hide();
$("section:first").show();
$("fieldset").hide();
$("fieldset:first").show();
});

</script>

<script>
#form section:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}

#form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
.hide{
  display:none;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the error that was causing the code to malfunction using Dreamweaver's error checker/lint. There was not a closing `</div>` tag for `<div class="form-row">`. This meant that the `<form id="myForm1"></form>` tags could not run properly because it was missing the closing `</div>` and had confused the program on the function of the code.

**Your code here that had the error:**

```
<form id="myForm1">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Book" value="" required><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Second Book" value="" required ><br>

    </div>
</form>
```

I also recommend that you put you `<script></script>` tags inside your `<head></head>` or `<body></body>` tags since it will load better or slightly faster as well as it is common practice to do so.

Reference for where `<script></script>` tags should go: [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Link to HTML Lint to marginally reduce less errors in your code: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

To use the HTML Lint, just copy your code, paste it into the website, and then click Validate HTML.

You're Welcome. :D